# Google Places store results in Mysql with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would like to store the results that i get from the google places api to a mysql database with php.

This is my javascript/ html and php now:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=weather,geometry,visualization,places,drawing&amp;&key=API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {

  var input = document.getElementById('id_address');
  var options = {
    types: ['address']

  };
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code") {
          var postal_code = place.address_components[i].long_name;
          document.getElementById('postal_code').value = postal_code;

        }

      }
    }
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
```

My Input field:

```
 <input type='text' name='route' class='form-control' id="postal_code" disabled>
```

And then i do a INSERT INTO with php

$_POST['postal_code'];

Can someone help me with this? I don't find a solution, search also on google etc.

Comment: What's not working?  What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: postal_code in C:\xampp\htdocs\google_places_action.php on line 24

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: @Ivan86 Yes! Thank you. I have searched all week for this and it was just something simple. That i did not think about this. Thanks again for the fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<input type='text' name='route' class='form-control' id="postal_code" disabled>
```

use:

```
<input type='text' name='route' class='form-control' id="postal_code" readolnly="readolnly" />
```